Troubleshooting SQL C# Language Extensions
I'm currently trying to get language extensions working in SQL Server 2022 for C#
When I try to run the code using "sp_execute_external_script" I get the following error.
"External language runtime for 'Dotnet' could not be provisioned. Error code 0x800704d4."
I've looked in the SQL Logs, Windows Event Viewer and Extended Events for any more information on the error but can't find anything.
I've been following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/tutorials/search-for-string-using-regular-expressions-in-c-sharp?view=sql-server-ver16
So far these are the steps I've taken:

Installed the Machine Learning feature of SQL Server & restarted machine
Confirmed the SQL Launchpad service exists
Updated the account that the launchpad service runs under to an account that is admin on the machine and checked the Local Policy entries
Made sure both the account that the launchpad runs under and the "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" user have full permissions on the folders "E:\SQL_Data\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL" and "E:\LanguageExtensions"
Installed .NET SDK 6.0.419
Downloaded the dotnet-core-CSharp-lang-extension-windows-release.zip file
Compiled the regex sample code into a dll via visual studio with target framework set to 6.0
Ran the following code in SQL to set up the language extension which runs without error

CREATE EXTERNAL LANGUAGE Dotnet
FROM
(CONTENT = N'E:\LanguageExtensions\dotnet-core-CSharp-lang-extension.zip', FILE_NAME = 'nativecsharpextension.dll' );
go

CREATE EXTERNAL LIBRARY regex
FROM (CONTENT = 'E:\LanguageExtensions\regex_language_ext\RegexExt.dll')
WITH (LANGUAGE = 'Dotnet');
GO


Then tried to run the sample using EXEC sp_execute_external_script at which point I get an error

Any help on this would be great as my googling has turned up very little on troubleshooting language extensions for SQL.
Many Thanks
